# react native using sha256

Tags: react-native, sha256

I'm trying to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sha256) react-native library to do sha256 hashing. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, Text, View} from 'react-native'
import {sha256} from 'react-native-sha256'

export default class CyrptoTest extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        sha256("test").then(hash => {
            console.log(hash)
        })
    }

    render(){
            return(
                <View style={{padding:30}}>
                    <Text>this is CryptoTest 1</Text>
                </View>
            )
    }
}
```

I am getting this error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sha256lib.sha256')`
I do not know why this is or how to fix this, any help is appreciated, thanks

PS:
Before I did any of this I first ran this in the command line:

```
yarn add react-native-sha256
react-native link
```

Also to run the app in my emulator on my mac I do this:

```
react-native start
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: How did you start your project? With react-native init command or using expo? If you started with react-native init, did you run the comman react-native link?

Comment: please look at my latest addition to my post, I hope that answers your question, if not let me know

Comment: It seems like linking does not work properly. I'm not sure why.

Comment: is this a problem your having to on your machine?

Comment: No. I have not used this library before and didn't test it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case I was using the react native cli debug server host & port for device, it was solved with a ./gradlew clean and recompiling the app on the phone.